Finding right master data value using AI/ML or Gen AI to avoid data fallouts
We have a requirement, where we are thinking of leveraging AI/ML or Gen AI.
We are getting sales data from retailers. The sales data has many attributes, which can fallout of the master data. Eg., Product Code, Retailer Name etc.,
Currently, these fallouts are handled manually by Data stewards. We want to reduce the fallouts by doing either fuzzy logic or nearest neighbor algorithms or using some predictive modeling to find the right master data value. We are using SQL Server Master Data Services as the master data management system.
But, the data which we have are mostly codes, textual values. So, can AI/ML or Gen AI help here or this case is not a good fit for them ?

E.g., For Product Code, B7 – 2700 , B7 – 27OO (note the alphabet O
instead of zero), 2700, B7 are all belonging to same Product Code.

